# How to attach onClick events to preview template in react-dropzone-component?

Tags: reactjs, dropzone.js, reactjs-flux

I am trying to use react-dropzone-component in reactjs, Everything works fine but after image is uploaded i want to add the onclick events to preview Template

Below is the config

> const djsConfig = {   addRemoveLinks: true,   params: {
>         userId: this.props.userId   },   previewTemplate:
>                     `<div class="dz-preview dz-file-preview" >
>                       <div class="dz-image"><img data-dz-thumbnail /></div>
>                       <div class="dz-details">
>                         <div class="dz-size"><span data-dz-size></span></div>
>                         <div class="dz-filename"><span data-dz-name></span></div>
>                       </div>
>                       <div class="dz-progress"><span class="dz-upload" data-dz-uploadprogress></span></div>
>                       <div class="dz-error-message"><span data-dz-errormessage></span></div>
>                       <div class="dz-success-mark">
>                         <svg width="54px" height="54px" viewBox="0 0 54 54" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
>   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
>   xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
>                           <title>Check</title>
>                           <defs></defs>
>                           <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
>                             <path d="M23.5,31.8431458 L17.5852419,25.9283877 C16.0248253,24.3679711 13.4910294,24.366835
>   11.9289322,25.9289322 C10.3700136,27.4878508 10.3665912,30.0234455 11.9283877,31.5852419 L20.4147581,40.0716123 C20.5133999,40.1702541 20.6159315,40.2626649 20.7218615,40.3488435 C22.2835669,41.8725651 24.794234,41.8626202 26.3461564,40.3106978 L43.3106978,23.3461564 C44.8771021,21.7797521 44.8758057,19.2483887 43.3137085,17.6862915
>   C41.7547899,16.1273729 39.2176035,16.1255422 37.6538436,17.6893022
>   L23.5,31.8431458 Z M27,53 C41.3594035,53 53,41.3594035 53,27
>   C53,12.6405965 41.3594035,1 27,1 C12.6405965,1 1,12.6405965 1,27
>   C1,41.3594035 12.6405965,53 27,53 Z" id="Oval-2"
>   stroke-opacity="0.198794158" stroke="#747474"
>   fill-opacity="0.816519475" fill="#FFFFFF"
>   sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
>                           </g>
>                         </svg>
>                       </div>
>                       <div class="dz-error-mark">
>                         <svg width="54px" height="54px" viewBox="0 0 54 54" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
>   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
>   xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
>                           <title>Error</title>
>                           <defs></defs>
>                           <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
>                             <g id="Check-+-Oval-2" sketch:type="MSLayerGroup" stroke="#747474"
>   stroke-opacity="0.198794158" fill="#FFFFFF"
>   fill-opacity="0.816519475">
>                               <path d="M32.6568542,29 L38.3106978,23.3461564 C39.8771021,21.7797521 39.8758057,19.2483887
>   38.3137085,17.6862915 C36.7547899,16.1273729 34.2176035,16.1255422 32.6538436,17.6893022 L27,23.3431458 L21.3461564,17.6893022 C19.7823965,16.1255422 17.2452101,16.1273729 15.6862915,17.6862915
>   C14.1241943,19.2483887 14.1228979,21.7797521 15.6893022,23.3461564
>   L21.3431458,29 L15.6893022,34.6538436 C14.1228979,36.2202479
>   14.1241943,38.7516113 15.6862915,40.3137085 C17.2452101,41.8726271 19.7823965,41.8744578 21.3461564,40.3106978 L27,34.6568542 L32.6538436,40.3106978 C34.2176035,41.8744578 36.7547899,41.8726271
>   38.3137085,40.3137085 C39.8758057,38.7516113 39.8771021,36.2202479 38.3106978,34.6538436 L32.6568542,29 Z M27,53 C41.3594035,53 53,41.3594035 53,27 C53,12.6405965 41.3594035,1 27,1 C12.6405965,1
>   1,12.6405965 1,27 C1,41.3594035 12.6405965,53 27,53 Z" id="Oval-2"
>   sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
>                             </g>
>                           </g>
>                         </svg>
>                       </div>
>                     </div>` };

is there any way i can do it?